# Help with the xlop package

Tags: xlop

How can I perform these types of exercises with the `xlop` package? If it is possible to use another package, I would appreciate if you tell me which package can perform this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible ...

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\newcommand\hole[2]{#1}
\begin{document}
\opadd[operandstyle.2=\hole{?}]{123}{456} \qquad
\opadd[resultstyle.1=\hole{?}]{123}{456} \qquad
\opadd[operandstyle.1.3=\hole{X},
operandstyle.2.1=\hole{O},
operandstyle.2.2=\hole{O},
operandstyle.2.3=\hole{F}]{789}{112}
\end{document}
```